# Concatenation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, concatenation

Not sure how to write this the correct way. i can make it work but when i view source it looks like this

```
<img "="" "style="width:30%; height:30%;"   src="correctsource"></img>
```

as you can see at the beggining of the image tag their is two extra quotes & a equal sign.

Here is my code

```
var img = $(this).attr('src');
  //grab the visible div and the div with class edititable within it and append image
  $(".open:visible").find('.edititable').append('<img src="' + img + '" "style="width:30%; height:30%;" ">');
```

Comment: extra quotes at end of `img` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to:

```
foo.append(
    $("<img />", { 
        src: img, 
        style: "width: 30%; height: 30%" 
    })
);
```

It's easier to avoid mistakes with mismatched quotes this way, and generally improves readability too

Comment: +1 But, please note that this method only works in [jQuery versions 1.4+](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you had too many double quotes in the string.

```
$(".open:visible").find('.edititable').append('<img src="' + img + '" style="width:30%; height:30%;">');
```

Answer (score 0):

remove last double quotes then it will work.You added one extra .

that is write like

```
 .................height:30%;">');
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, your string simply was formatted incorrectly. You had an extra " infront of style. Tech you wrote it as

```
$(".open:visible").find('.edititable').text('<img src="' + img + ' " style="width:30%; height:30%;" ">');
```

Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cLYf/